# How to update field-type table when a channel gets deleted?

Tags: add-on-development, fieldtype

I am trying to build a Expression engine field-type(add-on),where I will be storing the field-type data in a separate table(Ex:field_type_data).I am able to update the records of the table "field_type_data" whenever a entry or multiple entries gets deleted,through function delete($ids) in ft.fieldtypename.php which gets called whenever a entry is deleted and $ids is an array containing the ids of the entries that are deleted.

But I am not able to do the same when a channel itself is deleted by user.Because with the deletion of a channel all the entries related to that channel also gets deleted.

Can anyone help me please,how to and where I can know the list  of entries related to the channel when it gets deleted.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm... is no any special hooks for this in EE as I know. So possible solution is to create ext. on sessions_end or sessions_start and execute records cleanup in case if $_GET = "channel_delete" exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is a bit of a problem. I usually just ensure I always JOIN my custom table back to `exp_channel_titles` when I access data, so that if the entry has been deleted without my knowledge, it will not show up in the SQL query results.